# Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because t he target machine actively refused it

Tags: azure, azure-functions

```
*[2022-07-21T11:29:11.318Z] The listener for function 'Functions.BlobTriggerFunction' was unable to start.
[2022-07-21T11:29:11.319Z] The listener for function 'Functions.BlobTriggerFunction' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because the target
 machine actively refused it. System.Net.Http: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Private.CoreLib: No connection could be made because t
he target machine actively refused it.
[2022-07-21T11:29:12.311Z] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
[2022-07-21T11:29:12.312Z] Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Net.Http: No connection could be made beca
use the target machine actively refused it. System.Private.CoreLib: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.*
```

I have created azure function blob trigger using IntelliJ IDEA Java, after this i am trying to run it locally then it is giving me this error.

```
public class BlobTriggerFunction {
/**
 * This function will be invoked when a new or updated blob is detected at the specified path.
 * The blob contents are provided as input to this function.
 */
@FunctionName("BlobTriggerFunction")
@StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
public void run(
    @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "ys01/{name}", dataType = "binary",
            connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") byte[] content,
    @BindingName("name") String name,
    final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + name + "\n  Size: "
            + content.length + " Bytes");
    System.out.println("logger ");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

- This can be due to your port is already using by some other function or process so change to different port and check.
- Also make sure your local storage emulator is running. If not, start the Azure storage emulator.

Refer to [one of the workarounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/698846/listener-for-azure-function-was-unable-to-start-er.html) given by Mayank Bargali in Q&A Forum.

Comment: Can't we run the Azure Function without Azure Storage Emulator?

Comment: If you're running the Azure function locally through VS Code, Azurite Storage emulator is must prerequisite - that will be present in [VS Code extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Azurite.azurite)